# Two-dimensional array assistance

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I am new to creating arrays within Access and I have looked up a bunch of articles online that have provided some assistance.  I have created a two dimensional array and assigned values to each position with in the array. Now comes the fun part!! How do I ask for a two dimensional input, store the information, compare the user input with the array that I have already created, pass the matching value of the array to a calculation, and then display the results within Access? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I need more information from your question. You didn't state the data type of the values you are comparing, but since it is a "calculation" I assume that numbers are involved and I will use integers instead of floats or doubles for your 2D array in this example. Also, I don't know how to calculate the result, so I just made up a variable `CalculatedResult`.

```
Dim UserInput
UserInput = InputBox("Please enter a number", "Enter Number", Integer)
Dim CalculatedResult As Integer

For Each element In My2DArray
  If UserInput = element Then
    Area(element)
  End If
Next element

Function Area(number As Integer) As Void
    ' Code used for calculation
    Debug.Print CalculatedResult
End Function
```

You may need to do `DoCmd.PrintOut` for the print statement instead of `Debug.Print` to display the results for Access; I'm not familiar with VBA's relation to Access. The `For Each` loop saves a lot of programming time compared to nested For loops.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will try it.  

Comment: I am still playing with it

Comment: Hello. So I had to go a different route due to my hands being tied at work. IT has disabled certain functions and I don’t have permissions to enable them. I now have all my numbers as double, in one section 215 for statements to do the comparisons, and had to remove the arrays. Now I’m having issues with my loops not working, passing the values, and need to pass my results to a report without using DAOs or the like.

Comment: if I could upload a picture of my code this would be a lot easier. I will try to be as transparent as possible. One of my loops looks like this: do (next line) j = j +1 (next line) StartPoint = inputbox(“where are you starting node a through z”) (next line) endpoint = inputbox(“where are you ending node a through z”) (next line) loop until t = trips. Everything is double and “trips” is entered by the user. The starting and ending points are passed to 215 separate for loops that use both values to test if they are true. If true, then it should assign a numerical value to the variable “time”

Comment: “Time” is also a double and is used in a simple calculation such as (variable 1 + variable 2 + ...+) / (time + variable N). This calculated value and other user inputed values need to be passed to a printable report. Any ideas about how to fix this? Your assistances is always greatly appreciated. Thank you very much for everything